# Was this patent ever issued?

Tags: us20040158483

Does this constitute prior art? It looks like someone filed an application and walked away from it. What happened here?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the parts of the question separately:

**Issued?**

No, this is an application that never resulted in a patent.

**Prior art?**

Prior to what? The determination of something being or not being prior art is relative to some specific patent or patent application in question. Is is veritably a published document and would be useable as prior art against anything filed after its publication date. (Some simplifying)

It must have been fairly early in its field judging from the large  number of later patents that cited it. ,

**Walked away?**

Actually the inventor filed this, received multiple rejections over a two year period and responded to each rejection. The one response I looked at was very far off the required format. The responses were also deemed insufficient to overcome the rejections. The last rejection was a so-called "final rejection" that needed a particular type of response (and more fees). The required response and fees were not submitted. The application went abandoned in June of 2006.

[image]

He may have really had something valuable and new when this was filed ten years ago. If he had professional patent prosecution help he might have received a patent that would be valuable now.

**What happened?**

The way to find out for yourself what happened is to use the [USPTO's Public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair)  database. A quick search on Ask Patents will find some very good answers that include step-by-step instructions.

What happened is this application was written and pursued by the inventor himself without the help of a professional. The last thing he submitted was classified as a "miscellaneous incoming letter" in which he said the examiner never understood the invention and asked the patent office to tell him what to do to keep the application alive.

[image]

The next occurrence recorded is the patent office properly declaring it abandoned. I have not looked into the substance of the case, just its progression.

Comment: Thank you for an informative and helpful reply. I will study the case of the hapless Mr. LeCouturier for any object lessons it provides.   I am curious to know how the correspondence between the inventor and third parties (like Congressmen) ended up in this database. Did the inventor send copies of his correspondence to the patent office? Is that a usual practice?

Comment: Anything the applicant sends in under an application serial number ends up in the file. If you send something in by accident there is a way to petition to have it removed (expunged!) otherwise there it sits, relevant or not. He didn't send it in by accident and no, it is not done. Even if those letters said something they are very irrelevant other than to demonstrate that you are wasting the examiner's time. It isn't your "invention" being rejected it's your claim wording.

Comment: Examiner Jacques H. Louis Jacques sleeps well at night.